# APEX 3.2: Button to download interactive report data to Excel

Tags: oracle-apex

My requirements are to create two buttons.  One button that will download all of the data in an interactive report (Select * from DB_TABLE).  The other button will download the interactive report data based on filter items (Select * from DB_TABLE where Name = :P1_Name)

I thought about utilizing javascript:gReport.controls.download(); but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas or sites you can point me to?  Many thanks in advance.

And no, I don't know why they want two separate buttons to download the report instead of using the 'Download' button in the interactive report menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Request value of the button to CSV, so your link looks like `f?p=181:9:3839908094418724:CSV::::`
This will only perform the default CSV download though. There is however no built-in way to get the query from an IR. What i mean by that is that an IR which has filters applied.
If you only want to download results which are filtered through page items in the where clause, and don't bother with any IR filters or such, you could set up a report on another page, and have your link for a second button target that page (with CSV in request, but do use a redirect). The browser will prompt you with a save dialog, but you'll not end up on the page.